# How to create a recursive function containing a standard normal distribution?

Tags: r, recursion, normal-distribution

I have a question concerning the Brownian motion of a dust particle in the air. The equation is modelled in the x-direction by Xj = (Xj-1) + (vx dt) + (sigma Wj sqrt(dt)) and in the y-direction by the same case. The Wj is a standard normal distribution. The path of the dust particle must be modelled until the magnitude of its displacement is greater than or equal to 1 then the path must be plotted in a suitable manner. I'm pretty bad at coding overall and the code keeps messing up when I try to implement the recursive part of the function.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show your code. Describe exactly what you mean when you say it "messes up."

Comment: You probably don't need to write a recursive function. You can compute the `X(j)`s  using a loop on `j`.